# Javascript collection find values with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array shown as below. I want to know which values inside departure and arrival fields.

Array :

```
var data = {
    "origin": "Antalya",
    "destination": "IST",

    "flights": [{
        "provider": "thy",
        "time": "2017-07-07 10:30",
        "legs": [{
            "departure": "AYT",
            "arrival": "IST"
        }]
    },{
        "provider": "thy",
        "time": "2017-07-07 14:30",
        "legs": [{
            "departure": "AYT",
            "arrival": "ESB"
        },{
           "departure": "ESB",
            "arrival": "IST" 
        }]
    },{
        "provider": "pegasus",
        "time": "2017-07-07 06:30",
        "legs": [{
            "departure": "AYT",
            "arrival": "ADB"
        },{
            "departure": "ADB",
            "arrival": "IST"
        }]
    }]
};
```

I want to new array like this :

["AYT","IST","ESB","ADB"]

How can i handle it using lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using lodash:

```
let result = _(data.flights)
    .flatMap('legs')
    .flatMap(_.values)
    .uniq()
    .value();
```

First we get a flattened array of legs, transform that into a flattened array of the values of the properties of each leg, before finally getting the unique values.

Comment: Nice, but flatmap is normally used when you want each element in the array to go thru a manipulator function, in this case this is not needed, we should use flatten here, see my answer above.

Comment: You do need `flatMap` as you want to pluck the legs from the flights array. Your solution using flatten doesn't work because flatten takes one parameter which will be `data.flights` in this case. The `'legs'` passed into the flatMap as the second parameter will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Well loop through your data and create a string array, and then use the uniq function, like:

```js
var data = {"origin":"Antalya","destination":"IST","flights":[{"provider":"thy","time":"2017-07-07 10:30","legs":[{"departure":"AYT","arrival":"IST"}]},{"provider":"thy","time":"2017-07-07 14:30","legs":[{"departure":"AYT","arrival":"ESB"},{"departure":"ESB","arrival":"IST"}]},{"provider":"pegasus","time":"2017-07-07 06:30","legs":[{"departure":"AYT","arrival":"ADB"},{"departure":"ADB","arrival":"IST"}]}]};

var legs = [];
_.each(data.flights, flight => {
  _.each(flight.legs, leg => {
    legs.push(leg.departure);
    legs.push(leg.arrival);
  });
});

console.log(_.uniq(legs));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there a shorter way with lodash methods? :)

Comment: The solution using flatten doesn't work. See my comment below.

Comment: nope I realised I was using wrong lodash version in my jsFiddle :S https://jsfiddle.net/hk1key5v/ removed that part of the answer.